# Debug assembly code using Kdbg

Tags: linux, debugging, gcc, assembly, gdb

I have a project with one .c C source code and one .S assembly source code. Once compiled and linked, is there any way to debug .S code using Kdbg? I am calling one .S function from .c file but no code loads in Kdbg.

Comment: Why kdbg rather than WinDbg? And which compiler? And what build options? Details please!

Comment: please add gcc and ubuntu tags otherwise you question is ambiguous. Kdbg is a kernel debugger on windows.

Answer (score 3):

Add a .file directive in your source, like: .file "sourceasm.s". Kdbg will then use it as expected.

Answer (score 3):

I I just tried `kdbg` ([the KDE front-end for gdb](http://www.kdbg.org/), not the [Linux kernel debugger `kgdb`](https://elinux.org/Kgdb) of almost the same name).

It doesn't seem to have a proper disassembly mode like regular gdb's `layout asm`.  You can set the "memory" window to disassembly and the address to `$pc` (and it updates as you single step), but that ties up the memory window and isn't very flexible for setting breakpoints or scrolling backwards to instructions before the current RIP/EIP.

Even if you're debugging asm source, you sometimes want to have the debugger show you the real disassembly, as well / instead of the asm source.  For example in code that uses macros, or NASM `%rep` to repeat blocks.

AFAICT, `kdbg` is not a very good choice for asm debugging.  text-mode GDB with `layout asm` / `layout reg` is ok; see the bottom of the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for tips.  I've also tried https://github.com/cs01/gdbgui.  It has a disassembly mode, but it's not very nice.

---

As @ivan says, kgdb will let you do **source level debugging of asm source files** if you add enough metadata for it to know what source file the object came from.

- gcc: **Build with `gcc -g foo.S`**
- NASM: **Assemble with `nasm -felf64 -g -Fdwarf`** to include DWARF debug info.  (The NASM default is STABS debug info, which also works.)
- YASM: **Assemble with `yasm -felf64 -gdwarf2`**.

See [Assembling 32-bit binaries on a 64-bit system (GNU toolchain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain) for more about building static / dynamic binaries from asm source.

Comment: `kdbg is not a very good choice for asm debugging` Is *ddd* the only good choice for a GUI asm debugger on Linux?

Comment: @MaxB: IDK, I haven't gone looking.  `gdbgui` is not bad, and has probably improved since I last checked.  There might be something decent built-in to one of the IDEs, too, bug again I haven't checked.