# Debugging not highlighting current line

Tags: assembly, gdb, kdbg

Currently using kdbg and am finding that although I can debug the code and see the registers changing as expected, I cannot see the current line being highlighted in the source code window:

[image]

From examples on the web I'd expect to see a highlighted line in the source window.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and using kdbg 2.5.4.  Makefile contents is:

```
helloworld: helloworld.o
    ld -m elf_i386 -o helloworld helloworld.o

helloworld.o: helloworld.asm
    nasm -f elf32 -g -F stabs helloworld.asm -o helloworld.o
```

**Update 1**

It may or may not be related, but just for completeness, in the Xterm window 'KDbg: Program Output' window I can see the following:

```
warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted
```

**Update 2**

I updated the linker command as suggested in comments, but still get the same issue:

```
helloworld: helloworld.o
    ld -g -m elf_i386 -o helloworld helloworld.o
```

Comment: Most likely this is because you build without debugging information (without `-g`).

Comment: updated question to include how I've assembled and linked.

Comment: Looks like a bug in kgdb. You can try `layout asm` in standalone gdb. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2015523/72178.

Comment: Does `kgdb` have a `layout asm` / disassembly mode?  It looks like a nice UI, but when debugging C the step-instruction button seems really weird if there's no asm display!

Comment: Update, not really, all I could find was setting the memory pane to disassemble `$pc`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139786/debug-assembly-code-using-kdbg

Comment: @imrichardcole Try linking with `-g`. If that does not work, please make a transcript with `kdbg -t /tmp/gdb-transcript helloworld` and send it to the maintainer. Include `helloworld.asm` if possible.

Comment: Try with `nasm -g -Fdwarf` to generate the modern format of debug symbols.  `ld` can only include the debug info that NASM generates; it doesn't look at the original source.

Answer (score -1):

KDbg will highlight the current line when you start it from the command line and from the same directory where the assembly source code is located:

```
kdbg helloworld
```

Unfortunately, gdb does not report absolute paths when it is not started from the directory where the assembly source code is located. (It just says `helloworld.asm: No such file or directory.`) With the above work-around, gdb finds the file and can report sufficient information to KDbg so that it can display the source code.